# How to get description on Python Method?

Tags: python, methods

I know that to get help for a function, we use `help(func)` or `?func`, but what about a method? simply using `help(method)` or `?method` won't do anything.

I tried using a preloaded object name before a method, it worked. But are there any other way?

Comment: We're going to need more info that this. Is it a method provided by the python package or something that you downloaded using a package installation.

Comment: can you include some code?  `help(Class.methodname)` should work fine

Answer (score 1):

This format is inappropriate ?method and will produce an error. If you're having trouble understanding some Python object then `help()` will do.

```
help(func)
help(method)
help(Class.method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/help

Try these on Python shell.

```
help('random thing')
help('print')
help('def')
from math import * 
  help('math.pow')
```

Each one will show different results - but the last couple should help you understand how it works for what you are asking.